# How can I test whether or not a Chrome extension update will roll smoothly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, version-control

I have a few extension on the Chrome Web Store. The problem I have is that in another on of my extensions, I screwed up with an update, and it ruined the application unless it was reinstalled, unbeknownst to my user base. I want to test compatibility between versions, and my original idea went like so:

- Package current version into .crx
- Package new version into .crx using .pem from the current version
- Install current version in Chrome
- Install the new version over it as an update

This no longer works because Chrome disabled the updating extensions not installed from the Chrome web store. What way is there to test version compatibility before launch?

Comment: How could it require a reinstall instead of just pushing another update?

Comment: @DanielHerr because I could have made a mistake in the code, that messes up the extension upon an update. I need a way to test the update from the current version to the new one without actually distributing the update.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out to mark the published extension as either unlisted or trusted testers. Its discussed on this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272872/how-to-test-chrome-extension-for-auto-update-feature)